# Get Refresh Token for AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-cognito

I need to setup AWS Cognito to provide OAuth 2.0 authentication and authorization services for our API. We do not have a UI - it is a machine-to-machine app. I created a User Pool and Authorizer in AWS Cognito. `Authentication Flow` is set to `ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH`. The `Identity Provider` is `Cognito user pool`. With `OAuth 2.0 grant types` set to `Client Credentials`, this cURL works fine and returns an `access_token`:

```
curl \
-u "CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
-X POST https://our-user-pool.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

But we'd like to use refresh tokens as part of the authorization process, so when I change `OAuth 2.0 grant types` to `Authorization Code Grant`,

```
curl \
-u "CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
-X POST https://our-user-pool.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

returns an `Invalid request` error. Are there are other settings I'm missing, or maybe other parameters I need to add to the request? Or maybe there's a different endpoint I need to hit for this? I can't find anything in the Cognito docs on how to obtain a refresh token for the first time without a UI.

Comment: I’m struggling to see why. Refresh tokens are typically issued after a auth code grant in order to avoid having to reprompt the user for input. A client credential grant doesn’t have that issue.

Comment: Yeah, after a bit more research, for machine-to-machine interaction with an API, client credentials is the standard way of doing it, rather than authorization code grant.